# бот не выводит сообщение в discord когда в чат пишу !test1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import time


client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot word")

@bot.command()
async def test1(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Привет всем!",
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

   # emb = discord.Embed(title = ":OtherGames: CERBERUS \n Выбери игру, в которую ты играешь", colour = discord.Color.orange())
   # emb.add_field(value="роли нужны для поиска напарников \n")
   # await ctx.send( embed=emb )


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 868631163755974706:
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, client.guilds)

        roles = {
            'AYAYA': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='блять'),
            'roflanEbalo': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='тест1'),
            'default': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        }

        role = roles.get(payload.emoji.name)()

        if role is None:
            return None

        member = payload.member
        if not member.bot:
            await member.add_roles(role)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 868631163755974706:
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, client.guilds)

        roles = {
            'AYAYA': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='блять'),
            'roflanEbalo': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='тест1'),
            'default': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        }

        role = roles.get(payload.emoji.name)()

        if role is None:
            return None

        member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        if not member.bot:
            await member.remove_roles(role)




with open('Token.txt','r') as config_file:
    token = config_file.readline()

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вот. Все рабочее.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Activity, ActivityType

    
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот работает\n")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=Activity(name="сериал",type=ActivityType.watching)) # Это просто дополнительная фича от меня :)
    
@bot.command()
async def texte(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Привет всем)', colour = discord.Color.orange())
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)

@bot.command()
async def text(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("Привет всем)")
```

---

Вот твой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("c:"), intents=discord.Intents.all()) # <- ошибка была тут

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot word")

@Bot.command()
async def texte(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Привет всем)', colour = discord.Color.orange())
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)

   # emb = discord.Embed(title = ":OtherGames: CERBERUS \n Выбери игру, в которую ты играешь", colour = discord.Color.orange())
   # emb.add_field(value="роли нужны для поиска напарников \n")
   # await ctx.send( embed=emb )


@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 868631163755974706:
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, Bot.guilds)

        roles = {
            'AYAYA': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='блять'),
            'roflanEbalo': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='тест1'),
            'default': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        }

        role = roles.get(payload.emoji.name)()

        if role is None:
            return None

        member = payload.member
        if not member.Bot:
            await member.add_roles(role)

@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 868631163755974706:
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, Bot.guilds)

        roles = {
            'AYAYA': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='блять'),
            'roflanEbalo': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='тест1'),
            'default': lambda: discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)
        }

        role = roles.get(payload.emoji.name)()

        if role is None:
            return None

        member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        if not member.Bot:
            await member.remove_roles(role)



Bot.run('свой токен, или что у тебя')
```

Comment: вопросы возникли и возможно некоторые моменты не понятны:
1) при начале работы бота он не пишет что бот работает 
2) все равно не работает я пишу в чат !text а он не отвечает я могу скинуть весь код для полной картины

Comment: я сейчас добавил весь код для полной картины

Comment: Я добавил.
Я не понял одного, где ты увидел чтоб добавлялись сразу 2 "активатора" бота. В этом заключалась твоя ошибка. Ну еще ты там не исправил, то что я отправил первым. Все что касалось твоих вопросов я исправил. А что на счет остальных  действий снизу, я не посмотрел. 
В общем случае, то что тебе надо было, все работает. По крайней мере у меня. 
Кстати: я там исправил некоторые вещи под себя, поставишь свои обратно. [префикс, токен и др.]

Answer (score 0):

Чтож, я поизучал этот вопрос на примере нескольких ботов и заметил, что тут используется async и await, хотя модуль **asyncio** не импортирован, а ещё ты чёт странное в середине намудрил. Убери

```
client = discord.Client() # <---- эту строку
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command() # <---- и эту.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot word")
```

Ещё и зачем-то в этот кусок импортирован datetime.

Код в итоге должен выглядеть так:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot word")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Привет всем!"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Если в конце появится ошибка **discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.**, то напиши во вторую строку @bot.command() внутрь метода bot.command(**pass_context=True**)

Comment: Кстати, для простого ответа текстов делают просто await ctx.send('Привет всем!')

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вызывается клиент, а не бот, поэтому надо просто поменять `client.run()` на `bot.run()`.